# Version number for SQLite DB

Tags: android, sqlite

I am working on sqlite in my android app.

I am doing  `db.getVersion()` to get current version of my database.

it is showing  `3` in logcat.

even in constructor i set `4` as a version number.

```
public Helper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null,4);
    }
```

i am giving `4` it should take `4` as version number.

but its not behaving like this. it is showing `3` as version number.

please any suggestion.

UPDATE:-

```
    public class Helper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        public static final String  DATABASE_NAME = "helper.db";

        public static final String TITLE = "title";
        public static final String AUTHOR = "author";
        public static final String ISBN = "isbn";

        public Helper(Context context)
        {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null,4);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

                db.execSQL( "CREATE TABLE book1(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,title TEXT, author TEXT,isbn INTEGER);");
                Log.v("Create Table", "CREATE TABLE book1(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,title TEXT, author TEXT,isbn INTEGER);");

Log.v("version ", "Version number is "+db.getVersion());

}
```

Comment: I can't understand your question, please rephrase it.

Comment: What constructor? Which language and DB driver are you using?

Comment: i have added some information please review it

Comment: I believe that is because the database is already created. Try clearing your data and then run the application. It should create a new database with a version number 4.

Comment: i have tested many times . if i give 1  it show 0,for 2 its show 1...and so on

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are checking the version number in the onCreate function, why? the OnCreate function should only be called the first time the datbase is created from scratch, in this case it should build the DB as you require fitting to the version you are using.

Can you try checking the DB version after the DB has been created and you ask to get a readable or writable instance of it?

```
SQLiteDatabase db = new Helper(context).getWritableDatabase();
db.getVersion(); // what value do you get here?
```

check out the source code of android 4.1.1 SQLiteOpenHelper, here it seems as the db version should be 0 inside the onCreate function, I guess it might be implemented in another way on the version you are testing on.
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.java#242

Answer (score 6):

It seems like the db is already created by previous version of your code, try uninstalling the app from the device you're testing on , then re-install. this should give you version = 4

Comment: ok , you can uninstall from emulator by going to settings
then applications . chose your app and uninstall

Answer (score 3):

You have to drop the table inside oldversion database, override this function

```
 @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS book1");
        onCreate(db);
    }
```

that should be it.

to avoid data loss refer to this tutorial

http://denverdroid.blogspot.com/2010/04/how-to-non-destructibly-upgrade-your.html

or this

[How to update an SQLite Database and NOT lose all existing data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188839/how-to-update-an-sqlite-database-and-not-lose-all-existing-data)

Comment: why should i drop it ..i dont want my data loss.

Comment: I provided a new link above which can help you avoid data loss.

Comment: thanks to these link but this is not my question .my question .please see my question..thanks for new idea but this not the solution.

Comment: see i can put this Log.v("version ", "Version number is "+db.getVersion()); where you want .but onupgrade ,oncreate result is same ..it always show one number less to current

Comment: you get the oldversion of the database because it was not updated, that is why i am showing you properly to update the database to keep it up to date. Also mind as well put logcat code in the onupgrade function and display both oldversion and newversion

Answer (score 1):

I think you're providing the wrong constructor for your Helper class.  Try this:

```
  public Helper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory, int version) {
     super(context, name, factory, version);
  }
```

Your current constructor is telling Android that it is already at version 4 and there is no need to upgrade it.

Also, you need to provide an onUpgrade method as well.

```
  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // upgrade code
  }
```

Comment: you know what will problem i ll get if i use this constructor .in other activity if i call this class..instead of "this" , i need to pass 4 parameter there.

Comment: constructor not a problem. i tried with (context,version) two parameter

Comment: Can you show the code where you create the helper class?  Thanks.

Comment: @CobraHissssHissss..... are you saying that it worked with a different constructor?  Or that it failed in the same way (not upgrading version number)?  Thanks.

Comment: "Your current constructor is telling Android that it is already at version 4 and there is no need to upgrade it." No, that's not what the 4 in the constructor means, according to the docs (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#SQLiteOpenHelper(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory,%20int))

Comment: The version argument to the constructor means the version of the db that the app wants, not what version it already is. "version, int: number of the database (starting at 1); if the database is older, onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase, int, int) will be used to upgrade the database..."

Answer (score 1):

### TO CLARIFY THIS ISSUE ONCE AND FOR ALL:

```
 private SQLiteDatabase getDatabaseLocked(boolean writable) {
  ...
            db.beginTransaction();
            try {
                if (version == 0) {
   -------->      onCreate(db);      <---- YOUR QUERY ON VERSION IS HERE !!!
                } else {
                    if (version > mNewVersion) {
                        onDowngrade(db, version, mNewVersion);
                    } else {
                        onUpgrade(db, version, mNewVersion);
                    }
                }
   -------->    db.setVersion(mNewVersion);      <----   NEW VERSION IS SET HERE !!!
                db.setTransactionSuccessful();
            } finally {
                db.endTransaction();
            }
        }
...
}
```

SOURCE:
[public final class SQLiteDatabase](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.java)